# Building of docker container hangs randomly on M1

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I have a Dockerfile which I use for many years, and every time it was building perfectly before I got my new M1.

Now, 50% of the times (maybe even more) it hangs randomly on some random step. Usually it fails on thisone:

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ./wildfly-command.sh
```

And my `wildfly-command.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/wildfly
JBOSS_CLI=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh
JBOSS_MODE=${1:-"standalone"}
JBOSS_CONFIG=${2:-"$JBOSS_MODE.xml"}

function wait_for_wildfly() {
  until `$JBOSS_CLI -c "ls /deployment" &> /dev/null`; do
    sleep 1
  done
}

echo "==> Starting WildFly..."
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/$JBOSS_MODE.sh -c $JBOSS_CONFIG &

echo "==> Waiting..."
wait_for_wildfly

echo "==> Setup Datasource..."
$JBOSS_CLI -c --file=`dirname "$0"`/module-install.cli

echo "==> Shutting down WildFly..."
if [ "$JBOSS_MODE" = "standalone" ]; then
  $JBOSS_CLI -c ":shutdown"
else
  $JBOSS_CLI -c "/host=*:shutdown"
fi
```

And I see '==> Shutting down WildFly...'

However, ocasionally it fails on other steps as well.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
ARG PLATFORM
FROM --platform=$PLATFORM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly

# Install Maven
USER root
#RUN yum install -y maven && yum clean all

# Install necessary packages
RUN yum -y install wget

# Download and extract Maven
RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.1-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp \
  && tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-3.9.1-bin.tar.gz -C /opt \
  && ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.9.1 /opt/maven \
  && rm /tmp/apache-maven-3.9.1-bin.tar.gz

# Set Maven environment variables
ENV MAVEN_HOME /opt/maven
ENV PATH ${MAVEN_HOME}/bin:${PATH}


# Set Postgresql env variables
ENV DB_HOST postgres
ENV DB_PORT 5432
ENV DB_NAME postgres
ENV DB_USER postgres
ENV DB_PASS gjAFk3!Rk2#!lapA@
ENV hbm2ddl create
ENV DS_NAME PostgresXADS
ENV JNDI_NAME java:jboss/PostgresXADS

ADD https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.6.0.jar /tmp/postgresql-42.6.0.jar

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY input_files/wildfly-command.sh ./
COPY input_files/module-install.cli ./
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ./wildfly-command.sh
RUN chmod +x ./wildfly-command.sh
RUN ./wildfly-command.sh \
    &&  rm -rf $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history/

# Build the war
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src ./src/
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true

# Add deployments
ADD target/cryptonews-1.1.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin P@ssword --silent

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```